# Issue implementing validation rules in game

Tags: python, validation, math, input, while-loop

I am programming a version of the countdown game (from the UK television show) and I have an issue when implementing the rules for the arithmetic expression that the player types. I have four rules, each implemented with a while loop (i.e.: the input has to be an expression and not just a number, it can only have basic maths calculations (+ - * /), etc.)

This is a simplified form of what I have:

```
while #rule 1 is not respected:
   #ask for another input
   #check again
while #rule 2 is not respected:
   #ask for another input
   #check again
while #rule 3 is not respected:
   #ask for another input
   #check again
while #rule 4 is not respected: 
   #ask for another input
   #check again
```

The issue with this is the following: If a player violates, say, rule 4 and when asked for another input, violates rule 2, the second input isn't checked (neither for rule 2 nor for any of the rules before rule 4). How do I check all rules each time the player types another input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the four conditions using any of the following:

- `not (.. and ... and ...)`;
- `(not ...) or (not ...) or (not ...)`;
- `any(not ...)`;
- `not all(...)`.

Below I used `not all(...)`:

```py
def rule1(expr):   # expression contains at least one operation
  return any((op in expr) for op in '+-*/')

def rule2(expr):   # expression contains only numbers and operations
  return all(c in '+-*/0123456789 ' for c in expr)

def rule3(expr):   # don't know the rules of Countdown but love 42
  return ('42' in expr)

def rule4(expr):   # addition is okay a little but not too much of it
  return (expr.count('+') < 7)

def input_expr():
  expr = input('Enter your expression: ')
  while not all(rule(expr) for rule in [rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4]):
    expr = input('Expression was not okay. Enter again: ')
  return expr
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions and `try/except` blocks are a nice way to handle error checks like this:

```
while True:
   try:
       expr = input("I can has an input? ")
       assert "rule1" in expr, "Input needs to contain 'rule1'!"
       assert len(expr) < 20, "Input must be less than 20 characters!"
       assert len(expr.split) > 2, "Input must be at least 3 words!"
       break # all done!
   except AssertionError as e:
       print(f"Bad input: {e}")  # continue and try again
```